# BXSlider - reset slide counter

Tags: bxslider

I have a usage of BXSlider where I have a filter option which changes the loaded HTML which the BXSlider uses as the content for its carousel. Is there a way for me to kill the first version of BXSlider when I create a 2nd version? the slide count and current slide data persists from the first version and is messing up my 2nd version...

I am using the code here to display the current and total # of slides > http://www.antimath.info/jquery/bxslider-slides-counter/#comment-285598

Even with all the data for the first instance of the slider removed from the HTML using $('.bxsliderWrapper').empty(); the auto advance of the first slider persists????

How can I kill it?

I think I want to be able to stop the auto advance of the first instance of the BXSlider...

Answer (score 0):

OK so it worked by including a click function with `slider.stopAuto` within the original bxslider call function.